How do I make an arbitrary instance of a generic type?
My goal is to create arbitrary instances of type T: Arbitrary from the 'arbitrary' Rust crate from crates.io. Unstructured is a type from the same crate.
My first attempt:
fn random_object<'a, T: Arbitrary<'a>>(randomness: &'a [u8]) -> T {
    let unstructured = Unstructured::new(randomness);
    T::arbitrary_take_rest(unstructured).unwrap()
}

let mut randomness: [u8; 1000] = [0u8; 1000];
let mut rng: StdRng = SeedableRng::from_seed(seed);
rng.fill_bytes(&mut randomness);
let t: T = random_object(&randomness);

error[E0597]: `randomness` does not live long enough
   -> <file-name>:123
    |
97  |     
    |          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
120 |             let mut randomness: [u8; 1000] = [0u8; 1000];
    |                 -------------- binding `randomness` declared here
...
123 |             let t: T = random_object(&randomness);
    |                        --------------^^^^^^^^^^^-
    |                        |             |
    |                        |             borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                        argument requires that `randomness` is borrowed for `'a`
...
147 |         }
    |         - `randomness` dropped here while still borrowed

The only way I could get the random_object function to work is if randomness has a static lifetime. My only solution so far involves unsafe code:
fn random_object<'a, T: Arbitrary<'a>>(randomness: &'static [u8; 100000]) -> T {
    let unstructured = Unstructured::new(randomness);
    T::arbitrary_take_rest(unstructured).unwrap()
}

let mut rng: StdRng = SeedableRng::from_seed(seed);
let t: T = unsafe {
    use std::ptr::addr_of;
    use std::ptr::addr_of_mut;
    static mut RANDOMNESS: [u8; 100_000] = [0u8; 100_000];
    rng.fill_bytes(&mut *addr_of_mut!(RANDOMNESS));
    random_object(&*addr_of!(RANDOMNESS))
};

Is there a better way that avoids the use of unsafe?
Minimal reproducible example that requires the arbitrary crate with the derive feature:
use arbitrary::Arbitrary;
use arbitrary::Unstructured;
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::Rng;

extern crate arbitrary;

struct A;

trait Trait<'a, T: Arbitrary<'a>> {
    fn foo(&self) -> Vec<u128>;
}

fn random_object<'a, T: Arbitrary<'a>>(randomness: &'a [u8]) -> T {
    let unstructured = Unstructured::new(randomness);
    T::arbitrary_take_rest(unstructured).unwrap()
}

impl<'a, T: Arbitrary<'a>> Trait<'a, T> for A {
    fn foo(&self) -> Vec<u128> {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        let mut randomness = [0u8; 1000];

        let t: T = {
            rng.fill_bytes(&mut randomness);
            random_object(&randomness)
        };

        vec![42]
    }
}


Your unsafe "solution" allows data races and is thus unsound.

Minimal reproducible example, requiring the arbitrary crate.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f631dada533452607e78947c499fddf

You need to take for<'a> Arbitrary<'a>.

The question I linked is just about a function, but it applies to your Trait just the same. You need to make sure you're free to pick any lifetime with a HRTB.
